Kindly explain these verses of Manunsmriti?
Manu Smriti Chapter IX
या पत्या वा परित्यक्ता विधवा वा स्वयेच्छया ।
उत्पादयेत् पुनर्भूत्वा स पौनर्भव उच्यते ॥ १७५ ॥
If a woman abandoned by her husband, or a widow, of her own accord, marries again and bears a son, that son is called ‘the son of a re-married woman.’—(175)
सा चेदक्षतयोनिः स्याद् गतप्रत्यागताऽपि वा ।
पौनर्भवेन भर्त्रा सा पुनः संस्कारमर्हति ॥ १७६ ॥
In case she be still a virgin, or having gone away comes back,—she is fit to undergo re-marriage with her second husband.—(176)
What does 176 mean when she returns?
Returns to whom? Her first husband or the second husband?
How is marriage to second husband permissible as remarriage is not prescribed in hinduism?

Re-marriage may be prescribed in Parashara smriti

Kindly quote the verse

One second I don't have access to Parashara Smriti, so I am using Medhatithi's Manu Smriti commentary with the following being said, "Others hold that after the said time, the woman may deviate from chastity;—as says smother Smṛti text—‘When the husband is lost, or dead, or become a renunciate, or impotent, or an outcast—in the event of these five calamities smother husband is permitted for women.’ (Parāśara)."

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201438.html
